# Development workflow for Spring Boot + Maven + Docker + IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, docker, intellij-idea, docker-compose

I would like to ask for some recommendations for development workflow for application with stack mentioned in the title. Before I switched to use Docker all I had to do was:

1. Go to start.spring.io and download project starter
2. Import it into intelliJ
3. Develop features, hit green arrow to start app or red square to stop and repeat it with every change in code

Now when I switched to docker, after step 2, I do this:

1. Create Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml (where I start my app and also mysql service).
2. Right click on docker-compose and hit run. Then it builds my app image (i use --build flag in my run configuration so it builds images every time it I hit run on docker-compose) and starts two services: app and mysql, and everything works.

The problem is when I change sth in my code then I have to:

1. Execute mvn clean and install steps manually, to produce new jar under /target folder
2. Then stop previous docker compose and run it again. Then it builds new images from what is in /target

I would rather like to have something like one-click solution, like it was before I started to use docker. So when I change code then I press only one button and new image is generated and run with all changes applied. Is it possible? Do I miss something? Could you tell me if your workflow is similar to mine? Maybe you could recommend some tools or different config?

Comment: Why don't you create a script?

Comment: You don't need to have to do `mvn clean install` simply `mvn clean package` is sufficient. The question is why do you use Docker? Really needed? Just run in your IDE working on Code running tests etc. ? The CI solution uses `mvn clean deploy` to publish the artifacts in our repository manager (maybe we produce a docker image if needed) ...but I don't do that locally ...extremely seldom ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set up Spring Boot dev tools to live reload inside a Docker container.

Ensure spring-boot-devtools dependency is in your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
  <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

Then create a docker-compose.yml file with

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  backend:
    image: maven:3.6.3-jdk-8
    command: mvn spring-boot:run
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/mymaven:rw
    working_dir: /usr/src/mymaven
```

This uses the [Maven Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/maven) so when you run `docker-compose up`, it will run the image and map your source code folder as a volume. Then maven will run the application using `mvn spring-boot:run`

Whenever you make a change to the source code, it will reload with the same functionality as `mvn spring-boot:run`.

Comment: I had to additionally: File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment → Compiler and enable 'Build project automatically' and Then: File → Settings → Advanced Settings and enable 'Allow auto-make to start even if developed application is currently running'.

Comment: My instructions don't need a specific IDE, you can run using the command line. But intelliJ might need additional configuration

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a separate release module - *project-name*-release - which brings down the old image, build the new image and run/publish it
2. Use [docker maven plugin](https://github.com/spotify/dockerfile-maven) in the config

Sample project - https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-spring-boot-docker